# How to Save a vector as an original Bin file using the importAgilent.m file

Tags: matlab, bin

I am using the importAgilent.m file to import and plot variable x,y saved from an oscilloscope.

I use the simple code to plot the voltage time trace saved on channel 1

```
[x,y]=importAgilentBin('myFileName.bin',1)
plot(x,y);
```

I want to process the variable by shortening it and then save it in the same format as the original bin filename/structure.

The problem is not shortening the variable but saving the variable x,y as a bin file? As i would like to use it in the oscilloscope after processing it.

At the bottom of the following link you can download the importAgilent.m file and a bin file. As i cannot attached a zip file on here.

[ImportAgilent.m file](http://www.keysight.com/main/editorial.jspx?cc=GB&lc=eng&ckey=1185953&nid=-32872.0.00&id=1185953)

Any ideas very welcome

---

To explain more about my research to answer the problem: Here is my simple code that does not open the new bin file: I am thinking it does not have the same structure as the original

```
close all; clear all; clc
[x,y]=importAgilentBin('myFilename.bin',1);
plot(x,y);
% Create new Bin file called nine
fileId = fopen('nine.bin','wb');

% Write file header
fileCookie = fwrite(fileId, 2, 'char')
fileVersion = fwrite(fileId, 2, 'char')
fileSize = fwrite(fileId, 1, 'int32')
nWaveforms = fwrite(fileId, 1, 'int32')
fwrite(fileId,[x:y],'uint32');
fclose(fileId);

% Try and open the new bin file using importAgilentBin.m
[x2,y2]=importAgilentBin('nine.bin',1);
plot(x2,y2);
```

I am trying to use the importAgilentBin file code as a guide to structure a script to save the new data.But i am not sure on what i am doing wrong and a bit stuck! Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking questions you should show your research, read [ask]. Also, googling a bit is easy to find on [Matlab doc](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html) how to write binary files.

Comment: Thanks Salvador, i have not much research data as i am just settuo up an experiment, it is to measure the voltage potential in a liver between to points. I am fairly new to matlab, but am really enjoying it so far.

Comment: Thanks Salvador, i have not much research data as i am just setting up an experiment, it is to measure the voltage potential in a liver between two points. I am fairly new to matlab, but am really enjoying it so far. I could use the code:** fileID = fopen(myFilename.bin','w');
fwrite(fileID,y,'int32');
fclose(fileID);** to write the variable y to the bin file, but it would not have the same structure as the original and would not be able to be read by the oscilloscope or again processed in matlab. I thought this would be the right place to get some help to modify the importAgilent file ?

Comment: It is the right place to get help solving concrete problems, but it is not a coding service, if i don't see any research done, i encourage the users to try to find, if there is any research done, but the user is stuck, then if i can help to solve the issue, i just help :)